# store variables on user model laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

my user model has 3 fields: username, password and category_id
so when i auth the auth object will have all of the 3 variables, but i want to add the name of the category that is on other model
and i get like:

```
$category = Category::find(Auth::user()->category_id);
$category_name = $category->name;
```

so the question is who can i add $category_name to the Auth::user() object, in order to retrive it every time he is logged like this:

```
Auth::user()->category_name
```

i try Session::put("category_name","Category 1") when you loggin, but when i close the windows and open it by the last closed windows, it delete that variable.
i want to store the variable since the person login, untill the person logout, but if the person has logged in and close the window and then the person re open the page the variable must be filled

Comment: please explain more so we can provide the best answer, do you have an error or what ? and what 'exactly happens' and how exactly you want it to be, please further explaining, (the first code works fine? and the second? if you want to show the variable every time a certain view is open you can use view composers with caching

Comment: basically i want to store a variable on all the logged session, even if i close windows and then i open it again

Comment: ok first ,when you close the windows and open it back, are you still loged in or not?

Answer (score 0):

try this

in your User model add the following function

**EDIT** try this

```
public function category_name()
{
    return \Cache::remember('category_' . $this->id , 60, function()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category')->get();
    });
}
```

now everytime you use

```
Auth::user()->category_name
```

you will have the name

this will eco the name in your View

```
{{ Auth::user()->category_name }}
```

**NOTE :**  this code is not the best solution even if it worked for you, this is open for changes, i just want you to get the point that if you want to access something via `Auth::user()->getname` you have to add the `getname function` in the User model

and by the way can you show us the relation you set in you model? because that would make it easier

an exemple
if you have something like this in ur model(hasone)

```
public function category() {
        return $this->hasOne('category');
    }
```

you can do this

```
Auth::user()->category->name
```

Comment: i do the second one but with belongsTo and it works but the thing is that i want to cache it, to not do an sql every time i {{write Auth::user()->category->name}} do you get it?

Comment: yes add the top code to your Model, it will only do a query every 30 min ( you can increase the amount of time)  you can access the cached result like this {{ Auth::user()->category_name }}

Comment: it shows me the error: Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Comment: try to remove the ->get()

Comment: try without the cache first so we can spot the probleme ,keep only this inside the function and try,  return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');

Comment: i have solved with $category = Category::find(Auth::user()->category_id);
$category_name = $category->name; Cache::forever('category',$category_name );

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eloquent Accessors

In User model

```
 public function setCategoryNameAttribute()
 {
    $categoryID = $this->category_id;
    $category = Category::find($categoryID);
    return $category->name;
 }
```

You can access category name like

```
Auth::user()->category_name
```

Comment: i use the relationship on laravel by public function category() {
        return $this->hasOne('category');
    } but it does a query every time i call it, i want to store on a variable to reduce number of querys